# Massive performance issue with nested ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol

I use a nested ItemsControl to display hierarchical data. Problem is that this is terribly slow even with little data. Its also blocking the UI-Thread completely until data is loaded. What am I doing wrong here?

Code to generate Demo-Data and bind it to the ItemsControl:

```
private void SetupDemodata()
    {
        ObservableCollection<Folder> demoData = new ObservableCollection<Folder>();

        const int numberOfFolders = 1;
        const int numberOfFiles = 1;
        const int numberOfLines = 300;

        Random randContentLength = new Random();


        for( int indexFolders = 0; indexFolders <= numberOfFolders; indexFolders++ )
        {
            Folder newFolder = new Folder {FolderName = string.Format( "DemoFolder {0}", indexFolders )};

            for( int indexFiles = 0; indexFiles <= numberOfFiles; indexFiles++ )
            {
                File newFile = new File {FileName = string.Format( "DemoFile {0} -> {1}", indexFolders, indexFiles )};


                for( int indexLines = 0; indexLines <= numberOfLines; indexLines++ )
                {
                    newFile.ContentLines.Add( new FileContentLine
                        {
                            LineContent = GetRandomString( randContentLength.Next( 80 ) ),
                            LineNumber = indexLines
                        } );
                }
                newFolder.Files.Add( newFile );
            }
            demoData.Add( newFolder );
        }

        this.icFolders.ItemsSource = demoData;
    }

    private static readonly Random random = new Random();
    private static string GetRandomString(int length )
    {
        length = Math.Max( length, 3 );
        byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
        random.NextBytes( bytes );
        return Convert.ToBase64String( bytes ).Substring( 0, length );
    }
```

The models:

```
public class Folder
{
    public List<File> Files { get; set; }
    public string FolderName { get; set; }
    public Folder(){ this.Files = new List<File>();}
}

public class File
{
    public List<FileContentLine> ContentLines { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public File() { this.ContentLines = new List<FileContentLine>(); }
}

public class FileContentLine
{
    public int LineNumber { get; set; }
    public string LineContent { get; set; }
}
```

And the XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Grid>

            <Grid>
                <ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" x:Name="icFolders" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" >

                    <!-- Folder -->
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Folder}">
                            <Grid Margin="0">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Border Grid.Row="0" BorderThickness="0,1,0,1" BorderBrush="#c5c5c5">
                                    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource styleGridGradient}">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Label Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource styleLabelBold}" Content="{Binding FolderName}" />
                                            <Label Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource styleLabelBold}" Content="{Binding Files.Count}" />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                                <Border Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="0,1,0,1" BorderBrush="#c5c5c5">
                                    <Grid Style="{StaticResource styleGridGradient}">
                                       <Label Foreground="#666666" 
                                       Margin="5,0,0,0" 
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                       Content="{Binding FolderName}"  />
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>

                                <!--Files -->
                                <ItemsControl Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Files}" >
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:File}">
                                            <Grid Margin="0">
                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <Border Grid.Row="0" BorderThickness="0,1,0,1" BorderBrush="#c5c5c5">
                                                    <Grid Style="{StaticResource styleGridGradient}">
                                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                                        <Label Grid.Column="0"
                                                           Foreground="#666666"
                                                           Margin="5,0,0,0"
                                                           VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                           Content="{Binding FileName}" />

                                                        <Button Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" MaxHeight="25" Content="Open File"/>

                                                    </Grid>
                                                </Border>

                                                <!-- Lines -->
                                                <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding ContentLines}" Background="White">
                                                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:FileContentLine}">
                                                            <Grid Margin="0" Height="20">
                                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="35" />
                                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                                                <Border Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" BorderBrush="#c5c5c5">
                                                                    <ToggleButton>
                                                                        <Label Content="{Binding LineNumber}" />
                                                                    </ToggleButton>
                                                                </Border>

                                                                <Border Grid.Column="2" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" BorderBrush="#c5c5c5">
                                                                    <Border  Grid.Column="2" BorderThickness="0,1,0,1" BorderBrush="Red">
                                                                        <Label Height="20" Content="+" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                                                                    </Border>
                                                                </Border>

                                                                <Border Grid.Column="3" BorderThickness="0,1,0,1" BorderBrush="Gray">
                                                                    <TextBox Height="20" IsReadOnly="True"
                                                                             VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                                             VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                                                             Text="{Binding LineContent}" />
                                                                </Border>
                                                            </Grid>
                                                        </DataTemplate>
                                                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                                </ItemsControl>

                                            </Grid>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl>

                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Read about virtulization in WPF

Comment: Also it its hierarchical data that you are showing you might want to think about lazy loading as well

Comment: I am aware of virtualization but I don't know how to apply it in my nested scenario.

Comment: sorry for late response. Did you manage to solve it? Can you try to bottleneck the issue and lets say remove the hierarchy and ensure that it is due to the data and nothing else. Or try to supply less data then we know that Virtualization will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following property to all your `ItemsControl`s (root and nested ones):

```
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsPanelTemplate>
     <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
  </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```