# How to create a collection of collections?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, collections, wpf-controls

I have a collection of images on a canvas. Now I require multiple canvases each with its own collection of images. How would I implement this? Can it be done in the code behind?

Here is a simplified version of my collection of images for a single canvas:

```
<ItemsControl Name="canvasDataBinding"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
            Height="512"
            Width="512" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
            ClipToBounds="True">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas MouseMove="Canvas_MouseMove"
                MouseEnter="Canvas_MouseEnter"
                MouseLeave="Canvas_MouseLeave"
                MouseDown="Canvas_MouseDown"
                MouseUp="Canvas_MouseUp"
                Background="Transparent">
            </Canvas>

        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding Name}"
            Width="{Binding Width}"
            Height="{Binding Height}">
            </Image>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I believe I would need two `observableCollections`, one for the canvases and one for the images. Would I put an `itemsControl` inside the `DataTemplate` of the `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate`?

Comment: "Would I put an `ItemsControl` inside the `DataTemplate` of the `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate`?" Exactly.

Comment: @Clemens How do I manage the two different collections? I cant bind to the nested ItemsControl ItemsSource.

Comment: You would have to create an "outer" data item type, that has a public collection type property (e.g. an ObservableCollection) of "inner" data items (those that you already have). Then bind the outer ItemsControl's ItemsSource property to a collection of this type.

Comment: Something like shown in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17742402/1136211).